# Mysql Result consisted of more than one row SQL=INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql

While inserting for the first time it gave the following error:

> Result consisted of more than one row.

When I try to insert record for the second time, it gave me error with message: `duplicate entry`.

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `master_user` (`name`,`user_name`,`email`,`password`,`system_name_of_friend`,`system_no_of_friend`,`registered_from_site`,`registered_on`,`is_existing_user`)
VALUES ('FirstName LastName','username','demo@mail.com','8c71eede42e38709e9e836021b0b9b9b','','','site','','1')
```

Any help will be appreciated, and following is the table structure which will be a help to track this issue.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `master_user` (
  `master_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `system_name_of_friend` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `system_no_of_friend` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `registered_from_ip` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_from_site` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_existing_user` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`master_user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ukMasterUser_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1293 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall remove the `'` enclosing the bit value, it would have been interpreted as a character, which is more than 1 bit. And make the date `null` as well, instead of inserting `''`.

```
INSERT INTO `master_user` (`name`,`user_name`,`email`,`password`,`system_name_of_friend`,`system_no_of_friend`,`registered_from_site`,`registered_on`,`is_existing_user`)
VALUES ('FirstName LastName','username','demo@mail.com','8c71eede42e38709e9e836021b0b9b9b','','','site',null,1);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eda2ff